# Can someone down-vote solely because you posted a link to a particular (.doc) file format?

Tags: support, down-votes

This is the concerned post:
[Antenna Diversity: two Yagi antennas to the Rx and Rx/Tx u.fl-male points on the wifi-NIC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122996/antenna-diversity-two-yagi-antennas-to-the-rx-and-rx-tx-u-fl-male-points-on-the)

A quick summary:

> 1. I posted some data from a file (bcm4312.DOC) I found on the net as a block-quote.
> 2. In my post I mentioned that the file I was quoting from was bcm4312.doc
> 3. A guy replies asking me to paste a hyper-link to the file since he's "intelligent" but "lazy" (probably too lazy to google).
> 4. I link to the concerned doc file.
> 5. Then he asks for another link since this is a doc file and might contain viruses!
> 6. I tell him that viruses are also contained in .pdf and ask him to clarify what file-format he wants it in. (I wish to point out here
>      that I have no control over what's posted on the Internet AND that I
>      have QUOTED the relevant material in my post)
> 7. I get down-voted.

I suspect that I am being trolled by someone with a high "reputation". I'd like to point out that after building up a decent rep, someone could spend some quality time making life miserable for new people.

Is there a dispute resolution mechanism for downvotes or an "op" (IRC operator) who can question frivolous down-votes?

Comment: How do you know it was because of the file and not something else?

Comment: How do you know the downvote was from the person who was leaving the comments? (That's very often not a safe assumption to make, unless they specifically said they were downvoting)

Comment: @random you're not answering the question posed but raising a new one - my point is that there is a dispute over the down-vote that was cast - 1. Is the voting system completely anonymous? 2. Can it be challenged? 3. Is it arbitrary? 4. Is there a dispute-resolution mechanism? 5. Where can I find documentation on down-voting (the rules for voting)?

Comment: @random - I never said that it was "because of the file" - those are your words not mine.

Comment: @Vek.M1234 Why else would you suspect you're being trolled and that some high-rep user is making your life miserable, unless you suspect the downvoter and commenter are the same person? (It's a reasonable assumption to make, just startlingly often not a correct one.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no dispute mechanism, and individual downvotes don't get disputed.

From your comments:

> 1. Is the voting system completely anonymous? 2. Can it be challenged? 3. Is it arbitrary? 4. Is there a dispute-resolution mechanism? 5. Where can I find documentation on down-voting (the rules for voting)?

1. Yes.
2. No, with the exception of [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/152515), which generally gets resolved automatically. One downvote is not something you can really challenge.
3. Not completely. People won't downvote you for totally arbitrary reasons. They will if your question is low quality per their subjective judgement. (Mouse over the downvote icon, and read the tooltip.)
4. No, except for serial downvoting.
5. See the serial downvoting link.

In short: you got one downvote. You won't really know why, unless someone says so. If your question is of decent quality, you'll probably get upvotes too, and it won't be a major issue.

Comment: Thanks - that helps a bit. Just to be absolutely clear:- With this post - it's reasonably useful (in my opinion) and yet its got 4 down-votes. The mouse-over says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear, or not very useful" - that's pretty subjective. Almost anything can be found to be lacking in effort, or unclear.. a guy who doesn't read carefully may have a problem understanding, and down-vote. Am I to understand that: It's your vote, and you can do whatever you feel like with it (for all practical purposes). Voting being subjective by design and nature.

Comment: Yes, voting *is* subjective. I doubt we could make it objective if we tried, and keep it useful at the same time.

Comment: @Vek.M1234 The downvotes here are likely because of the "does not show any research effort" part of the tool-tip... there's lots of information in the help center about voting.

Comment: @Vek I'm not the downvoter, but please take note that voting in Meta can also mean agreement/disagreement. Probably some users just read the title and disagree with that. Maybe others read your question about downvote dispute and disagree with that "feature-request". This kind of request has always been shot down since ever. And well, that's only my opinion since I couldn't know the real reason they downvoted. Cheers!